# Can't disable redirect to root page after refresh in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

In a large Angular 4 application after refreshing page router redirects to root '/' page ignoring current url. In case of typing full url same scenario. Does anybody faced with such problem?

Comment: Params aren't auto forwarded. Check out this issue for solutions that need to be applied to the server host: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10466

Comment: Please check if you get the redirect from the server when requesting index.html or the Angular does it.